# Data can not be added to MySQL table due to foreign key constraint violation

Tags: mysql, database

Data can not be added to tables due to ERROR 1452 (23000). How can this be solved?

```
mysql> insert into lecturers (lecid, fname, lname) values (600, 'Brandon', 'Jenkins');

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`handin`.`lecturers`, CONSTRAINT `lecturers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`unitid`) REFERENCES `unit` (`unitid`))

| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| lecid  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| fname  | varchar(35) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lname  | varchar(35) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| unitid | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Question was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constraint is enforcing "referential integrity". Along with the NOT NULL constraint, the foreign key constraint is telling the database that each and every row in the `lecturers` table *must* reference a row in the `unit` table.

The error message indicates that if the INSERT statement were to add the row, the row added would *violate* that constraint. The INSERT is disallowed because the row being added would violate the constraint.

---

We see the INSERT statement is not providing a value for the `unitid` column.

MySQL will provide the default value for the `unitid` column *-or-* there's a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that is assigning a value to it.

We see the `unitid` column is declared to be `NOT NULL`, so we know a `NULL` value isn't being assigned. (If a NULL was being assigned, we'd be violating the NOT NULL constraint, and we would get a different error message.)

The foreign key constraint is basically telling the database... when I add or update a row in `lecturers`, go check the `unit` table and verify that the value we're assigning to the `unitid` column *exists* in a row in the `unit` table.

The error message is telling us that the check *failed*. The value we're trying to assign to the `unitid` column in `lecturers` is *not found* in the `unitid` column of the `unit` table.

---

MySQL is disallowing the insert because the row would *violate* the specified constraint.

That's "what's going on".

---

If you want to add a row to `lecturers` table, supply a valid value for the `unitid` column...

```
 INSERT INTO lecturers (..., unitid) VALUES (...,'42')
 --                          ^^^^^^              ^^^^
```

Where the supplied value `'42'` is found in a row in the `unit` table. That is, this query would return at least one row (normally, just one row)...

```
 SELECT unitid FROM unit WHERE unitid = '42'
```